# Machine learning model with all categorical variables

Tags: r, machine-learning, python, categorical-data, variance-inflation-factor

I have a data with 250 predictor variables, all of them are categorical variables (`0=Absent, 1 =Present`) and my Y variables is probability. (Y=1 means highest chance of occurrence of an event and Y=0 means lowest chance of occurrence of an event).

I am interested in the following analysis:

1. See the relationship between all 250 variables (to find multicollinearity)
2. Variable reduction
3. How the 250 predictor variables are affecting Y

But, to see how these 250 predictor variables are correlated, I was thinking to use VIF and correlation matrix. But I am not sure if I can use VIF and correlation matrix for all categorical predictor variables.

For variable reduction, can I use PCA or factor analysis for categorical variables?

To build a model, which machine learning models should be good to start with?

Comment: Don't ask three separate questions as one question. And I agree with MrFlick that none of the three questions are on-topic here. Also, to aid in your searching, unless your variables are dummy or one-hot encoded, I would just call them "binary" rather than "categorical".

Answer (score 0):

To look at correlation among categorical variables, you can use [Phi and Cramer's V](http://uregina.ca/~gingrich/ch11a.pdf). You can eliminate variables that have high Cramer's V. Likewise PCA or factor analysis are good ways to reduce the dimensionality of your data.

As for good machine learning models to start with, that is a very subjective question. I would start with simpler models like OLS regression, and then see potential improvement in performance from increasing complex models like random forest. Model tuning and selecting the right sample to build on will also affect performance, often more than the algorithm itself.